# How to plot daily evolution of variables while maintaining unique label even if index position of label changes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've a score tracking script that generates a dataframe exported in `json` daily. In order to open such `json` file I run something along these lines

```py
import json
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

# Directory where the JSON files are located
json_dir = 'data/teamName'  # Update with your actual directory path

# Get the list of JSON files in the directory
json_files = [f for f in os.listdir(json_dir) if f.endswith('.json')]
data = []
for json_file in json_files:
    with open(os.path.join(json_dir, json_file), 'r') as f:
        player_stats = pd.read_json(f,keep_default_dates=True)
```

But, in order to give a working example of this behavior I can provide this following script.

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

day1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("01/01/2023", "%d/%m/%Y")
day2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("02/01/2023", "%d/%m/%Y")
day3 = datetime.datetime.strptime("03/01/2023", "%d/%m/%Y")

listPlayers =["Player1", "Player2", "Player3", "Player2", "Player1", "Player3", "Player1", "Player5", "Player3"]
listScores = [1.2, 3.4, 5.0,3.0, 1.4, 6.0,3, 2, 6.5]
listDays = [day1,day1,day1, day2, day2, day2, day3,day3,day3]

for i in range(1,4):
    myDF = pd.DataFrame({"Name":listPlayers[(i-1)*3:3*i], "Scores":listScores[(i-1)*3:3*i],"Days":listDays[(i-1)*3:3*i]})
    print(myDF)
    print("break")
```

What I need to do is to plot the evolution of a player's score and the evolution of the team daily even if the index position of the player name changes or the player itself is remove from the team (or another player is added). So what I want to show is that for instance in day 3 player2 gets switched by player5 (yet I want to plot the participation of player2 in days 1 and 2). And I want to have a unique label for each player. Is that even possible in such a variation of the dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get your input data is not clear but based on your loop, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your previous code
...

data = []
for i in range(1,4):
    myDF = pd.DataFrame({"Name":listPlayers[(i-1)*3:3*i], "Scores":listScores[(i-1)*3:3*i],"Days":listDays[(i-1)*3:3*i]})
    myDF = myDF.pivot(index='Days', columns='Player', values='Scores')
    data.append(myDF)

df = pd.concat(data, axis=0)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey, this works wonders. I didn't know pivot could do this. In my real `json` I track over 20 parameters of basketball matches for each player. So all I need to do is to actually copy the initial dataframe and pivot for each parameters which is kind of easy. I'll need to also look into some better ways to display all the lines since I can have from 12 to 32 players playing for a team each "season" I analyze. Thank you so much

Comment: If you have multiple parameters, take a look to seaborn and lmplot.

Comment: This is great! I'll have a look for sure. Much appreciates